# Devoff() error for file that does not exist in R

Tags: r

Error in dev.off() :    QuartzBitmap_Output - unable to open file '/Users/maryklisi/.local/share/rstudio/notebooks/BB2E2ADD-MixSIAR_0131/1/2145816261437704/clnqr9wnj985t_t/_rs_chunk_plot_001.png'

Keep getting this error when trying to run any plot() and ggplot() code. It comes up after restarting R countless times. That file/directory does not exist and I cannot get it to stop. Appreciate any help!

I've tried dev.off() and graphics.off() and it still comes up all the time.

Comment: I think you are beleaguered by an ancient, lingering save.image()? Yes response at the end of a forgotten prior session [Startup](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html), `R then loads a saved image of the user workspace from ‘.RData’ in the current directory if there is one (unless --no-restore-data or --no-restore was specified on the command line). ` This is a 'perhaps'... Still a little head scratch over the reference to a file exists while the file doesn't, but this seems to describe the behavior and how it might be arrived at. Startup worth reading.